# Python or C for a Qt application and security against reverse engineering

Tags: decompilation, c, python, obfuscation, qt

I actually have two choices : **C** or **Python** to create my application.
On my application users will need a key (on start) to access it, the key will be verified with an algorythm on the user's computer. I'm searching for the best language to make the reverse more difficult. I know it's impossible to make an application 100% protected againt this.
When looking for Python protection I saw this [question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22648/best-way-to-protect-source-code-of-exe-program-running-on-python), and so I'm wondering if **C** is better than **Python** for this kind of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code written in either language can be reversed, I think the bigger issue here is that the key checking is all performed locally. If someone can RE the algorithm, then they can create a keygen for anyone to use.

I'd suggest that you create a web service to validate the keys, and don't expose the algorithm to reversing.

The software could still have the key check disabled, and be distributed with a crack or pre-cracked. It's all about raising the bar high enough that no-one wants to bother spending the time breaking it.

So definitely use obfuscation, packing, encryption, anything to make reversing more time consuming.